# Am I using LINQ correctly to apply a variable amount of filters?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq

I'm populating a DataGrid in my .aspx page and have some dropdowns on the page for filtering the data that appears in the grid.  I'm trying to use LINQ to filter the data in the DataTable that I bind to on page_load and on the SelecedIndexChanged events of the drop downs.

Here's my current approach:

```
Dim filteredData As DataTable = (From d In rawDataTable
                            Select d).CopyToDataTable

        If Me.cbFilter1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then

            filteredData = (From f In filteredData
                            Where f.Field(Of Date)("ADateField").Year = Me.cbFilter1.SelectedValue
                            Select f).CopyToDataTable

        End If

        If Me.cbFilter2.SelectedIndex > 0 Then

            filteredData = (From f In filteredData
                            Where f.Field(Of String)("AStringField") = Me.cbFilter2.SelectedValue
                            Select f).CopyToDataTable

        End If

        If Me.cbFilter3.SelectedIndex > 0 Then

            filteredData = (From f In filteredData
                            Where f.Field(Of Boolean)("ABooleanField") = (cbFilter3.SelectedValue = "Yes")
                            Select f).CopyToDataTable

        End If

        ' ...and finally binding my grid to filteredData
```

Is there a cleaner and more efficient ways to do this?  How would you do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if my title correctly describes what I'm asking here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to be using is the `IQueryable` interface to handle adding multiple where clauses.  `IQueryable` allows you chain Where clauses to your query, while at the same time **deferring the execution** of the query until you're ready for the results.  The way you've outlined executes the queries multiple times. On top of that you're calling the `.CopyToDataTable` method each time, which may have some additional performance implications.

Aside from the fact that you should probably move away from DataSets and DataTables altogether, here's an example that will help you use them with IQueryable:

```
    ' Calling the AsQueryable extension method starts your query off as an IQueryable '
    Dim query = (From d In rawDataTable
                 Select d).AsQueryable()

    If Me.cbFilter1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        query = query.Where(Function(f) f.Field(Of Date)("ADateField") = Me.cbFilter1.SelectedValue)
    End If

    If Me.cbFilter2.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        query = query.Where(Function(f) f.Field(Of String)("AStringField") = Me.cbFilter2.SelectedValue)
    End If

    If Me.cbFilter3.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        query = query.Where(Function(f) f.Field(Of Boolean)("ABooleanField") = (cbFilter3.SelectedValue = "Yes"))
    End If

    ' At this point, you shouldn't even need the .CopyToDataTable() method. '
    MyGrid.DataSource = query
    MyGrid.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2):

try it.

```
filteredData = (From f In filteredData
     Where ((Me.cbFilter1.SelectedIndex > 0 And f.Field(Of Date)("ADateField").Year = Me.cbFilter1.SelectedValue) Or _
(Me.cbFilter2.SelectedIndex > 0 And f.Field(Of String)("AStringField") = Me.cbFilter2.SelectedValue))
     Select f).CopyToDataTable
```

Answer (score 2):

Why perform the `CopyToDataTable` each time? I would construct the query from the original data and do this step at the end.

```
Dim query = From d In rawDataTable Select d

If Me.cbFilter1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
    query = query.Where(Function(f) f.Field(Of Date)("ADateField").Year = Me.cbFilter1.SelectedValue)
End If

If Me.cbFilter2.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
    query = query.Where(Function(f) f.Field(Of String)("AStringField") = Me.cbFilter2.SelectedValue)
End If

If Me.cbFilter3.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
    query = query.Where(Function(f) f.Field(Of Boolean)("ABooleanField") = (cbFilter3.SelectedValue = "Yes"))
End If

Dim filteredData As DataTable = query.CopyToDataTable
```

Note: It is perfectly legal to combine different where clauses like this. The result is the same as concatenating the conditions with "And".

Comment: Nice.  That's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Instead of LINQ, use DataView on DataTable -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx

filteredData.DefaultView.RowFilter = "AStringField = " & Me.cbFilter2.SelectedValue

and

filteredData.DefaultView.RowFilter = "ADateField.Year = " & Me.cbFilter1.SelectedValue

etc. etc.

so you dont create new datatables but filter it.